# Array of annotations as parameter to an annotation, in Scala

Tags: spring, scala, annotations

There are plenty of questions about passing an array as a parameter to an annotation, this is not a dupe of those.

I would like to use a Java-land annotation that takes an **array of annotations** as a parameter, e.g.

```
@ManagedOperation
@ManagedOperationParameters({
  @ManagedOperationParameter(name="start"),
  @ManagedOperationParameter(name="end")
})
def stuff(start: String, end: String): Unit = ???
```

But this is not valid syntax in Scala, nor is

```
@ManagedOperation
@ManagedOperationParameters(Array(
  @ManagedOperationParameter(name="start"),
  @ManagedOperationParameter(name="end")
))
def stuff(start: String, end: String): Unit = ???
```

so what is the correct way to do this, if it is even possible?

BTW, I even [checked all of github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ManagedOperationParameters+extension%3Ascala&type=Code&ref=advsearch&l=) to see if any Scala devs are using this (Spring JMX) annotation.

Comment: I'll need to check that it works, there is no need to ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In scala the inner annotation should be used as regular type:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
  property = "moduleType",
  defaultImpl = classOf[PuppetModule]
)
@JsonSubTypes(Array(
  new Type(value = classOf[PuppetModule], name = "puppet"),
  new Type(value = classOf[PluginModule], name = "plugin")
))
trait Module {
  val moduleType: String = if (this.isInstanceOf[PuppetModule]) "puppet" else "plugin"
  val nodes: List[String] = List[String]()
}
```

Comment: I am using scala 2.12.3 now.  Compiler told me: "annotation argument needs to be a constant."  "new Type(...)" is invalid. Am i wrong ? Thank you.

Comment: @ZhuoYING I just test it on my env with 2.12.3 and it compiles... where do you see this error? IDE?

Comment: Yes, i am using `IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2`.

Comment: IDEA told me so. Do i need config IDE for this ?  when is use `mvn compile` by `scala-maven-plugin`, i get same result, same error messages. Thank you very much, sir.  @igreen

Comment: @ZhuoYING could you share sample project?

Comment: It worked today. :) But i do not know why.  Here is my example code with JPA api.  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yingzhuo/scala-annotation-problem/master/src/main/java/sap/jpa/User.scala  Thank you agin, sir.